# qcircuit.sty not found when visualizing a QISKit quantum scheme

Tags: latex, pdflatex, quantum-computing, qiskit

I followed [this manual](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/QISKit/qiskit-tutorial/blob/master/reference/tools/getting_started.ipynb) in order to visualize my [QISKit](https://www.qiskit.org/) v0.4.8 quantum circuit by means of the `latex_drawer()` function (in newer versions of QISKit the function is `circuit_drawer()`). However, I got the following error when running the code:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `qcircuit.sty' not found.
```

Is `qcircuit.sty` a part of QISKit? What is the best way to fix the issue?

By the way, this is the function that I use to produce the image of a circuit:

```python
def circuit_image(circuit, basis="u1,u2,u3,cx"):
    filename = 'circuit'
    tmpdir = 'tmp'
    if not os.path.exists(tmpdir):
        os.makedirs(tmpdir)
    filename_tex = filename + ".tex"
    filename_pdf = filename + ".pdf"
    latex_drawer(circuit, os.path.join(tmpdir, filename_tex), basis=basis)
    os.system("pdflatex -output-directory {} {}".format(tmpdir, filename_tex))
    images = pdf2image.convert_from_path(os.path.join(tmpdir, filename_pdf))
    shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
    return images[0]
```

Comment: Related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/visualization-of-quantum-circuits-when-using-ibm-qiskit

Comment: The tutorial is now dead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qcircuit` is a third-party LaTeX package that is not part of QISKit. If your LaTeX distribution does not come with this package, you can install it by yourself.

For example, for Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS do the following:

1. [Download](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/qcircuit) the zip-file
2. Unpack it to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex`
3. Run `sudo texhash`

For more information on installing LaTeX packages, see the following pages:

- [Best way to install packages for TeXLive in Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu)
- [How to install LaTeX packages for Tex Live?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371430/how-to-install-latex-packages-for-tex-live)